# What's the difference between ないわけにはいかない and ずにすまない？?

Tags: grammar

I think they both mean that you have to do something because there is a social pression like なければならい、but I'm not certain that I can use them interchangeably. Could somebody confirm it?

Comment: Great question! Sadly I could only give 1 upvote ;-( I have feeling we both say "of course, should have known" when someone comes with a good pair of sample sentences where they are not interchangeable)

Answer (score -2):

Come one natives! My best guess (yes, please downvote, as this site is not for guesses, but I hope @Alex16 and I at least get someone to answer ;-) )

ないわけにはいかない　has more of of the social pressure aspect (you are supposed to do X) while ずにすまない more likely means that there are some more "rational" (*) reasons for why failing to do X would cause problems.

(*) While it is "rational" to consider the other people when adjusting your message, here, by "rational", I meant simply a statement made without considering the "public opinion"

Comment: Please don't post a guess as an answer simply to motivate others to post answers. This is designed to happen naturally: unanswered questions are listed in the ["Unanswered" tab](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Unanswered) where unanswered questions with the most votes rise to the top, so if you don't know an answer, the best you can do to support a question is to give it an upvote and make sure it is clearly presented (for example, tag it appropriately, suggest improvements in comments, etc.).